# Detail View loaded twice

Tags: ios, master-detail

Hmm..

I have table view - detail view set up in my app.

The Master View uses regular code to pass the data to the detail view

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {            
    self.savedSelectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath =  self.savedSelectedIndexPath; //get the index path of the row selected        
        Event *event = [self.eventList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // now get the content of that row
        EventDetail *eventDetailView = (EventDetail *)segue.destinationViewController;

        eventDetailView.eventDetail = event;
    }
}
```

But for some reason, the detail view is being load twice.
The first load looks normal with the back button pointing back to the master view. But as first load finished, it reload the view again with the back button pointing back to the first load..

When I ran a NSLog in the ViewDidLoad, I can see the NSLog being logged twice...

I am not sure why it is doing this..

This is what I have in the ViewDidLoad in the Detail View:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"page loaded");
    self.eventTitleIB.text = eventDetail.eventTitle;
    self.eventLocationIB.text = eventDetail.address;
    self.eventTimeIB.text = eventDetail.eventTime;
    self.eventPointsIB.text = eventDetail.points;
    self.pointRuleIB.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Single Event is worth %@ points", eventDetail.points];
    self.eventDetailIB.text = eventDetail.eventDescription;

    NSLog(@"content loaded");
}
```

Thank you all for your help!!

Comment: In your storyboard, make sure there is no segue connecting the tableViewCell and the Detail Controller.

Comment: Thank you! I removed the reference and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the segue linked between the tableviewcell and the detailviewcontroller? In that case, remove [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];